# Wait for loading to complete

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, wait

I am running a script using selenium in java.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='FILE EXPLORER']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='color-blue select-row-icon ion-ios-circle-outline']")).click();
```

When the first line is executed there is a loading icon on the page,so it should wait till loading icon disappear and then execute 2nd line

I tried

```
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

But i want to run next line as soon as loading icon disappears

Comment: You have to find out the locator for loading icon and wait for the loading icon go off using explicit wait.

Comment: when loading the icon has xpath as /html/body/ui-block/div/div/i  what should i do

Comment: please add the following line after the first one to wait for the loading icon to disappear.  new WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/ui-block/div/div/i")));

Comment: I have added the full code in the answer section. please try it

Comment: @JitendraKumhar Can you consider updating us your exact manual steps and the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='FILE EXPLORER']")).click();
     new WebDriverWait(driver, 90).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/ui-block/div/div/i")));
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='color-blue select-row-icon ion-ios-circle-outline']")).click();
```

Comment: No its not running

Comment: irrespective of time(i.e is 90 here) it waits for some time after icon disappears

Comment: Yes that is normal. Change xpath and try